# XK02 internal error while accessing IXADRU

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I am trying to solve

> SAP NOTE 1158803

Note description:
This is due to data inconsistency in the address communcation tables  ADRU and respective Communication tables like

```
ADR2, ADR3, ADR4, ADR5....ADR13
ADR2....ADR13:
```

Stores communication data with the `VALID_FROM &VALID_TO`.
ADRU: Stores the corresponding `DEFAULT_FROM & DEFAULT_TO`.

This error happens when I go to a transaction Transaction Code XK02:

```
Vendor: 22113
and mark "Adress" press ENTER
Delete the Mobile Phone" and press ENTER, then the error message pops up: 
Internal error - access to IXADRU
```

Even after following all the steps in the sap note(all of them ex:creating a ZSAP function module,Z_ADRU_Correct etc) I still cant solve this bug.Now the note status is in progress.

There is also a second **Note 2554953** which is related to this bug but I cant download it !If anyone finds the documents to this note please send them to me.

[image: Picture]

Thank You in Advance for help!

Comment: `when I go to a transaction Transaction Code:` what tcode? And give error screenshot

Comment: @Suncatcher Q Updated

Comment: @PureAbap the [note 2554953](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2554953) just describes the problem and simply asks to refer to the [note 1158803](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1158803). There's Nothing to download from the note 2554953.

Comment: @PureAbap if the standard program (or the SAP note if you prefer) doesn't work, then open a ticket at SAP support

Comment: @SandraRossi thank you,I was hoping someone might have solved it!

Comment: Check up your ADRU table, if the errors described in 2554953 persist: `The Valid_to and Valid_from fields contain incorrect entries such as '00010101000000' or '99991231235959'`. BTW, only BASIS should implement the notes, and you are not a BASIS I assume

Comment: @Suncatcher actually I am