# Multiple exclude values in SELECT-OPTIONS?

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

I have to create a new initial selection for the material group and set as default view one with excluded mat groups `Z310` and `Z320`. However, when needed, the user should be able to include `Z320`

```
selection-screen begin of block b4 with frame title text-b04.
select-options: s_matkl for t023-matkl default 'Z310'.
selection-screen end of block b4.

INITIALIZATION.
s_matkl-sign = 'E'.
s_matkl-option = 'EQ'.
s_matkl-high = 'Z310'.
s_matkl-low ='Z320'.
MODIFY s_matkl.
```

I tried the above its not working. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data g_matkl like t023-matkl.

selection-screen begin of block b1 with frame title text-b01.
select-options: s_matkl for g_matkl.
selection-screen end of block b1.

INITIALIZATION.
  s_matkl-sign = 'E'.
  s_matkl-option = 'EQ'.
  s_matkl-low = 'Z310'.
  APPEND s_matkl. " <----------- 'APPEND' instead of 'MODIFY'

  s_matkl-sign = 'E'.
  s_matkl-option = 'EQ'.
  s_matkl-low = 'Z320'.
  APPEND s_matkl. " <----------- 'APPEND' instead of 'MODIFY'
```

When needed the user should modify the SELECT-OPTIONS.

Hope it helps

Comment: Just a comment, because I'm deeply allergic to TABLES, OCCURS and related commands: you can just define a global dummy variable to be used as a reference for your select-options.

Comment: I have an unanswered question ,If you care to take a look,it would be great![this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155562/internal-error-access-to-ixadru)

Comment: @VXLozano Done my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's told (although I cannot assure you) that God kills a kitten or a puppy every time TABLES and/or OCCURS are used.
XD

Comment: The question is about how to exclude the two values Z310 and Z320. So the first part of your answer is wrong because it would exclude any value between Z310 and Z320.

Comment: @SandraRossi Corrected. Best regards.

Comment: can the use include the Z320 if he wants to?

Comment: I mean in the condition for example `select from mara where matkl in gt_matkl`// or  `select from mara where matkl in s_matkl`?

Comment: @SandraRossi in the condition for example `select from mara where matkl in gt_matkl`// or `select from mara where matkl in s_matkl`

Answer (score 4):

If you are on newer releases, the following is a bit more concise:

```
DATA gv_matkl TYPE t023-matkl.
select-options: gt_matkl for gv_matkl.

INITIALIZATION.
 gt_matkl[] = VALUE #(
  ( sign = 'E' option = 'EQ' low = 'Z310' )
  ( sign = 'E' option = 'EQ' low = 'Z320' )
 ).
```

Comment: can the use include the Z320 if he wants to?

Comment: I mean in the condition for example `select from mara where matkl in gt_matkl`// or `select from mara where matkl in s_matkl`?

Comment: @PureAbap the user can include Z320 in the UI. He just has to remove it from the "Exclude Single Values" tab

Comment: @PureAbap No worries :)